# port services with nmap::scanner

Tags: perl, nmap

I used nmap scanner module on perl to do nmap on some hosts. I can pull out the open ports, but I want to be able to add services to the ports too, e.g tcp/22 SSH. When I run nmap on the linux machine using

```
 nmap -sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms host.ip
```

I get all the ports opened with their services, however I am not able to change my perl code to print out the services too.
My current code:

```
 my $scanner = new Nmap::Scanner;
  $scanner->register_scan_started_event(\&scan_started);
  $scanner->register_port_found_event(\&port_found);
  $scanner->scan('-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms host.ip');

 sub scan_started {
  my $self     = shift;
  my $host     = shift;

  my $hostname = $host->hostname();
  my $addresses = join(',', map {$_->addr()} $host->addresses());
  my $status = $host->status();

  print "$hostname ($addresses) is $status\n";
  }

  sub port_found {
  my $self     = shift;
  my $host     = shift;
  my $port     = shift;

  my $name = $host->hostname();
  my $addresses = join(',', map {$_->addr()} $host->addresses());

  print "On host $name ($addresses), found ",
        $port->state()," port ",
        join('/',$port->protocol(),$port->portid()),"\n";

    }
```

The output Im getting is

```
 (host.ip) is up
 On host  (host.ip), found open port tcp/22
 On host  (host.ip), found open port tcp/111
```

I'd really appreciate if I can get services along with the ports, like they come up when i enter the command manually.

Comment: Use [getservbyport](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_getservbyport.htm)

Comment: hey thanks! I was able to get the services by using getservbyport!!!!

Comment: `getservbyport` will only do a lookup in your system's `/etc/services` file. The Nmap scan may have discovered more detailed or different information, so use `$port->service()` to get an object with that information in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`service()`](http://search.cpan.org/~maxschube/Nmap-Scanner-1.0/lib/Nmap/Scanner/Port.pm#service%28%29) method of the `Nmap::Scanner::Port` object to get a [`Nmap::Scanner::Service`](http://search.cpan.org/~maxschube/Nmap-Scanner-1.0/lib/Nmap/Scanner/Service.pm) object. The accessors of that object roughly correspond to the fields of the `port.version` table described in the [Nmap API](http://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html#scripting-tbl-port-version-values).

Comment: Can you please give me an example? How will I incorporate that into my existing code? I'm pretty new to perl.

Comment: I used $port->service(), but the result didn't come out right,  Nmap::Scanner::Service=HASH(0x2a1b8c0)/

Comment: @LeRay `$port->service()->name()` or `$port->service()->product()` etc. See the [documentation I linked](http://search.cpan.org/~maxschube/Nmap-Scanner-1.0/lib/Nmap/Scanner/Service.pm).

Comment: Hey, I just used your method and I'm still getting these errors Nmap::Scanner::Port=HASH(0x1973108) instead of the name of the service. Also, how did you merge them to begin with, e.g $port->service()->name() can you explain that please?